# Django Image by Foreign Key and {% if / else %}

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I trying to access the `ImageField` of a Model which is assigned via `ForeignKey` to another Model.

I have different Animal Apps in my Projects, with almost the same structure, like the following models.py. On the landingpage of My Project I want to display the last 3 entry of every (Species) Models with Name and Picture. If the Species has no Picture I would like to display the ImageField of the Farm, which is connected via ForeignKey to my species.

**cows/models.py**

```
class Farm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    farm_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='farm_images/',
    max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

class Cows(models.Model):
    farm = models.ForeignKey(Farm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    entry_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    cow_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='farm_images/',
    max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
class HomeIndex(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context['chickens'] = Chicken.objects.order_by('-entry_date')[:3]
    context['cows'] = Cows.objects.order_by('-entry_date')[:3]
    context['cats'] = Cats.objects.order_by('-entry_date')[:3]

        return context
```

**home.html**

```
<….>
        {% for somecow in cows %}
        <div class="col-3" id="p1">
            <h2>{{ somecow.name }}</h2>
            <h2>{{ somecow.entry_date }}</h2>
            {% if somecow.cow_img %}
            <img src="{{ somecow.cow_img.url }}" alt="Mod" height="100">
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
<….>
```

Until here it worked.

---

But how can i access the FK.Model of the Model?

Or in other Words how can I tell Django:

*“If you found no cow Picture in Cow.Model,then show a Farm picture from the assigned Farm.Model?”*

As I understand I can access the assigned FK Models via

`{% for something in MyModel1.MyModel2_set.all %}`.

**my approach for home.html**

```
<….>
 {% for somecow in cows %}
    <div class="col-3" id="p1">
     <h2>{{ somecow.name }}</h2>
     <h2>{{ somecow.entry_date }}</h2>

      {% if somecow.cow_img %}
          <img src="{{ somecow.cow_img.url }}" alt="Mod" height="100">
      {% else %}

           {% for farm in somecow.farm_set.all %}
               {% if farm.farm_img %}
               <img src="{{ farm.farm_img.url }}" alt="Mod" height="100">
               {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<….>
```

So far I received no error Message, but I also see no Farm Image. I am sure I mixed something up in home.html. On the other Side I think I maybe I missed something in my view, something like `MyModel.objects.all()`

I am thankful for every hint.

Comment: Your code would have been correct the other way round `{% for cow in farm.cows_set.all %}` if you had wanted to display all the cow images for a particular farm btw. You use `_set` for the reverse relationship, not for the relationship itself (which is just `farm`).

Comment: Ah ok, so the other way around in my model structure. Good to know. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. There is only a single farm per cow: you just need to access it directly.

```
   {% else %}
       {% if cow.farm.farm_img %}
           <img src="{{ cow.farm.farm_img.url }}" alt="Mod" height="100">
       {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
```